# VueJS: Computed Property Is Calculated Before Created in Component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component, which looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'todos',
  props: ['id'],
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    todos () {
      return this.$store.state.todos[this.id]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData () {
      if (!this.$store.state.todos.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('getToDos', this.id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what's happening:

1. The component receives an `id` via props.

When the component loads I need to fetch some data based on the id

2. I have a `created()` hook from where I call a function `fetchData()` to fetch the data.
3. In methods, the `fetchData()` function dispatches an action to get the data. This gets and stores the data in Vuex store.
4. The computed property `todos` gets the data for this id.

The problem is that when the page first loads, the computed property `todos` shows up as undefined. If I change the page (client side) then the computed property gets the correct data from the store and displays it.

I am unable to understand why computed property doesn't update?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `getToDos` function aswell?

Comment: @T.Dirks getToDos is a Vues action that calls an external api for the data and then commits a mutation.   getToDos ({commit}, payload) {
    return api.content.gettodos(payload.is)
    .then(response => {
      commit('SET_TODOS', response)
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return error
    })
  }

Comment: My own understanding of the problem is that the computed is already set before we even call the method. And at that time, the store doesn't have the data. Later on, the method is called and the store is filled. But I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: You could trigger the `fetchData` function from your root component (`App.vue`), so all other components can work with that data and use `fetchData` in the components to update the data.

Comment: For now, I've chosen to solve the problem by preponing where I call the fetchData() and the issue is temporarily resolved. However, I would like to keep the question open as I really intend to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following approach:

**component.vue** (and just render `todoItem`)

```
  methods: {
    async fetchData () {
      const _this = this;
      if (!this.$store.state.todos.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
        this.$store.dispatch('getToDos', {id: this.id, callback: () => {
          _this.todoItem = _this.$store.state.todos[_this.id]
        }});
      }
    }
  }
```

**store.js**

```
  actions: {
    getToDos: (context, payload) => {
      // simulate fetching externally 
      setTimeout(() => {
        context.commit("getToDos__", {newId: payload.id, task: "whatever" });
        payload.callback();
      }, 2000);
    },
```

Comment: I think this will work, but why should we have to do this? Why can' I update the computed property value in some other way?

Comment: I don’t know how you’re updating the store but I’m asuuming you’re just updating an index in an array directly. vue can’t monitor such changes so you’ll have to use a trick described here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 0):

Base on [here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#created)

> When this hooks is called, the following have been set up: reactive data, computed properties, methods, and watchers. However, the mounting phase has not been started, and the $el property will not be available yet.

Answer (score -1):

I think what might solve it is if you create a getter for `todos`.

So in your VueX Store add:

```
getters: {
    todos(state) {
        return state.todos;
    }
};
```

And than in your `computed` use:

```
computed: {
    todos () {
        return this.$store.getters.todos[this.id]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't solve the problem. In some other threads I read suggested to add a watcher but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: A watcher won't do you any good I think, can you perhaps edit your question to show all the relevent code? So the component which uses it, the dispatch methods and the mutation methods? If you show all the relevant parts we might get a better understanding of where the problem is